# "o" before recent phone number, what does it mean

Tags: iphone, contacts

I just realized I got some recent contacts who have an "o" before their phone numbers when I'm adding a recipient after writting a text message, what does it mean?

I'm sure it's the letter "o" and not a zero because it appears when I search for "o" when adding a recipient. And it doesn't appear as capital letter before the number, it appears like "o961231234" and those contacts are not on my list, but they do appear as recent contacts.

Please, I'd really appreciate if somebody could answer this

Comment: Are you sure it is a letter "O" or is it the number zero "0"?

Comment: I'm sure it's the letter "o" and not a zero because it appears when I search for "o" when adding a recipient. And it doesn't appear as capital letter before the number, it appears like "o961231234"

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Could you please update your question with the following information that may be helpful to those who may be able to answer?  Phone model (5, 5S, 6, 6S etc), iOS version (9, 10 etc), what you have tried already (restart phone, update software, etc.)  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The letter 'O' before a telephone number is for OFFICE.
'F' for FAX